# UIDatePicker Cancel Overlaps

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

The CANCEL area is over the top of the date, the picker still works but is hidden under the cancel button.

This code used to work so I am guessing its something with the newer OS?

I haven't needed to mess with the iPhone code for a while and now find a problem with a date picker. So I am not up to speed at all on XCode but trying to muddle through to see what the problem is. I guess I will eventually get up to speed again and figure out what is wrong, but if anyone can tell me what it is that would be awesome.

```
-(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

    switch ([actionSheet tag] ) {
        case 1://date

        {    
            NSDate *d;

            UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 116)];

            [pickerView setTag:100+[actionSheet  tag]];

            [pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];



            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

            [pickerView release];

            NSArray *subViews = [actionSheet subviews];

            [[subViews objectAtIndex: SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)]; 
           [[subViews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];



        }

            break; 

    }


}



- (IBAction)btnDate:(id)sender {



    UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 

                             initWithTitle:@"Pick the date" 
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Select"
                             , nil];

    [asheet setTag:1];
    [asheet showInView:[self.view superview]]; 

    [asheet setFrame:CGRectMake ( 0, 117, 320, 383)];
    [asheet release];

}
```

Comment: FYI - `UIActionSheet` isn't designed to support adding subviews (even though many people do it).

Comment: See this post on UIDatePickerView heights. I think some of your issue is that in iOS 7 the height of the UIDatePicker has some default values and it's not clear that even setting the frame can successfully adjust it. [SO question on UIDatePickerView height](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18970679/35499)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess the real problem is the UIdatepicker has taken on a new twist. I can eliminate the CANCEL button but that isnt the right way to fix this. This is for sure something in the latest OS, just have to find a way to fix it.  The subviews are just a way to get the tap (click). I can take those out and the cancel is still in the middle of the date.  There doesnt seem to be anything to move the cancel to the proper location.  It used to default to directly above the select.